# More than one Dropbox account, how do I change the default startup account?

Tags: account-management, dropbox

I have two Dropbox accounts.  I use one the most.  It is the default on all of my computers except for one.

How can I change that one so that the main Dropbox account opens on startup?

Comment: How can you have "two Dropbox accounts"? The syncing client only allows you to connect one